# How to setup PHPStorm and its git client so that I could monitor more repos under the project root

Tags: git, symfony, phpstorm

My project consists of a root git repository that in itself contains other git repositories. I often have to make changes in more than one repository to complete a task. Is there a way to setup PHPStorm in such a way that I could see changes in all the repositories when I use the menu item VCS/Show changes?

Example structure is:

```
    projectRoot (repo1 - modified) 
    --- vendor
       --- repo2
       --- repo3
       --- repo4 (modified)
```

So the question is when I run the See Changes in the root, how to see the changes in the vendor repos as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using git subtrees instead of having repositories within your repository. Submodules and the like are not a particularly good practice, and can make your life as a developer a bit more difficult. Subtrees would make it easier.

You may find some more information here: http://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/